# How can I use MapApply[f] into this list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list

```
list = {{-5, -5, 6}, {-5, -4, 7}, {-5, -3, 5}};
```

I tried

```
 list = {{-5, -5, 6}, {-5, -4, 7}, {-5, -3, 5}};
f[m_, n_, d_] := {x == 3 t + m && y == 4 t + n, d};
MapApply[f]@list
```

I get

[image]

How can I get in the form

```
{\{x=3 t-5,y=4 t-5\},d=6}}
```

Comment: I do not understand your output. Is this what you mean? `Map[f[Sequence@@#]&,list]`  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUlTl.png)

Comment: Redefine: `f[m_, n_, d1_] := {x == 3 t + m && y == 4 t + n, d == d1};` and then `f @@@ list`. ??

Comment: @Nasser You are right. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Syed It works nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

list = {{-5, -5, 6}, {-5, -4, 7}, {-5, -3, 5}};
```

Change `f` to

```
f[m_, n_, dd_] := {{x == 3  t + m, y == 4  t + n}, d == dd};

MapApply[f]@list

(* {{{x == -5 + 3 t, y == -5 + 4 t}, d == 6}, 
    {{x == -5 + 3 t, y == -4 + 4 t}, d == 7}, 
    {{x == -5 + 3 t, y == -3 + 4 t}, d == 5}} *)
```

Or,

```
f @@@ list
```